# Multi selection inside a Grid - SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to implement a Multi selection inside a dynamic Grid.
With this code, it selects graphically all the elements together, basically they all change color. It saves the data from the selected one, but graphically they are all selected, and I can't select and save more than one at a time.
I think the problem could be the grid, but I also tried to change the grid with other libraries, but it didnt change anything.
Before I had simply an array and it works, now getting the data from the database it is not.

I'm still using and have to use swiftui 1, so I dont have the grid offered in the new swiftui.

I'm using this library for the grid, https://github.com/spacenation/swiftui-grid, the modular grid one, since I have this events that comes from the database.

Thanks.

```
struct ItemsEventSelectionView: View {

@ObservedObject var eventItems = getEventItems()

@State var eventSelections = [EventItem]()

@State var style2 = ModularGridStyle(.vertical, columns: .min(70), rows: .fixed(40))

@EnvironmentObject var globalDataObservableObject: GlobalDataObservableObject
    
var body: some View {
    ZStack(alignment: Alignment(horizontal: .center, vertical: .top)) {
        Group {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(UIManager.bgGradient)
                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        }
        
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            
            
            
            ScrollView(self.style2.axes) {
                
                Grid(self.eventItems.events) { event in
                    
                    HStack {
                        MultipleSelectionEvent(title: event.name!, isSelected: self.eventSelections.contains(event)) {
                            
                            
                            if self.eventSelections.contains(event) {
                                self.eventSelections.removeAll(where: { $0 == event })
                            }
                            else {
                                self.eventSelections.append(event)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                
            }.gridStyle(self.style2)
        }
    }

}
}




struct MultipleSelectionEvent: View {
var title: String
var isSelected: Bool
var action: () -> Void

var body: some View {
    Button(action: self.action) {
        HStack{
            
            if self.isSelected {
                
                
                Text(self.title)
                    .font(UIManager.einaBodySemibold)
                    .foregroundColor(UIManager.hBlue)
                    
                    
                    .padding(.vertical, 7)
                    .padding(.horizontal, 10)
                    .background(UIManager.hBlueLight)
                    .cornerRadius(6)
                
            } else {
                
                Text(self.title)
                    .font(UIManager.einaBody)
                    .foregroundColor(UIManager.hDarkBlue)
                    .padding(.vertical, 7)
                    .padding(.horizontal, 10)
                    .background(UIManager.hLightGrey)
                    .cornerRadius(6)
            }
        }
    }
}
}



class getEventItems : ObservableObject {

let didChange = PassthroughSubject<getEventItems,Never>()

@Published var events = [EventItem]() {
    didSet {
        didChange.send(self)
    }
}

func getEventItems() {
    
    EventItemViewModel().fetchEvents(complete: { (eventItems) in
        self.events = eventItems
    })
    
}

init() {
    getEventItems()
}

}
```